# Dataframe of pandas not showing all information I need

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of source IP connection and timestamp of that connection, I want to count all connections made by an IP address in a specific minute , I already prepared my dataset ( it's clean and can be used ), but I have a problem when I try to get the dataframe that contains 3 columns `Time`, `Source`, `Count`.

This is my code :

```
connection_count = {} # dictionary that stores count of connections per minute
source = pdata_frame['Source'] # source address
#print (source)
temp = pdata_frame['Time'] # time
#print(temp)
new_count_df =  pd.DataFrame(columns=['time', 'source', 'couted cnx'])
for s in source: 
    for x in temp :
        if  x in connection_count :
            value = connection_count[x] 
            value = value + 1  
            connection_count[x] = value

        else:
            connection_count[x] = 1

    df2 = {'time': x, 'source': s, 'couted cnx': connection_count}   
    new_count_df = new_count_df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    #print (new_count_df)   
print (new_count_df)
```

when I print the new_count_df it doesn't show me what I want.

[how the data should be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM9SX.png)

[My original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38ool.png4)

> Sl Num;Time;Source;Destination;Volume;Protocol 1;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.108;52.24.43.67;60;TCP 2;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.108;50.19.254.134;82;UDP 3;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.1;192.168.2.112;102;ICMP 4;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.1;192.168.2.112;102;ICMP 5;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.117;192.168.2.1;80;DNS 6;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.112;50.19.254.134;74;TCP 7;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.1;192.168.2.112;102;ICMP 8;25/10/2018
>   05:46:00;192.168.2.112;46.137.188.54;74;TCP 9;25/10/2018
>   05:47:00;192.168.2.108;52.25.66.250;60;TCP 10;25/10/2018
>   05:47:00;192.168.2.108;52.24.43.67;60;TCP 11;25/10/2018
>   05:48:00;192.168.2.108;52.24.43.67;60;TCP 12;25/10/2018
>   05:48:00;192.168.2.1;192.168.2.108;86;ICMP 13;25/10/2018
>   05:48:00;48:02:2e:01:83:15;Broadcast;60;ARP

Comment: what does it show you instead?

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide some sample data as well.

Comment: I believe your if clause contains redundant information. Couldn't you just replace all of that with connection_count[x] = connection_count[x] + 1, or even connection_count[x] += 1?

Comment: I added a link to image show how I want the data be displayed

Comment: also a link to my origine data that I wish to count

Comment: I dont think you need a for loop for this,  would `temp.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Source', freq='1M')).count()` give you what you want?

Comment: @dubbbdan not so sure. The OP needs to group on both `time` and `source`. @M.Bou could you add your original data as text instead of an image? A representative sample (10 lines roughly) is typically enough. People willing to help may wish to test their answers before posting, and it's impossible to do without data (we cannot grab data from an image).

Comment: I added data to the code

Comment: KeyError: 'The grouper name Source is not found' I get this issue when I apply groupe by

Comment: @M.Bou  my syntax was off.  See my answer for correct syntax and example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your connections are at even minutes, as indicated by your example data, all you need is [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'SI Num': [1,2,3,4], 'time' : ['10/25/2018 05:46:00','10/25/2018 05:46:00','10/25/2018 05:46:00','10/25/2018 05:46:00'],"Source":['192.168.2.108','192.168.2.108','192.168.2.1'
                   ,'192.168.2.1']})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df.groupby(['time','Source'])['Source'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

which returns:

```
                 time         Source  count
0 2018-10-25 05:46:00    192.168.2.1      2
1 2018-10-25 05:46:00  192.168.2.108      2
```

If the connections aren't made on even minutes, you would need to resample to minutes before you aggregate the data.  Conveniently, you can acheive this using [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) within the groupby statement. 
Something like:

```
df = df.groupby(['Source',pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='1min')])['Source'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: dubbbdan Thnak you very much you helped me alote , sir can you please provide with source where I can learn about manipulating time in python for example this code I want to run it in minutes and seconds and even fraction of second , so I  was thinking of using epoch time instead may be but I still don't know axately what to do

Comment: @M.Bou  Have a look at the [offset ailiases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) that can be used within `pd.Grouper`.  The offset aliases range from annual `Y` to nanoseconds `N`.

Comment: Also, if you end up with timestamps that `pd.to_datetime` cant infer from the data you will need to use the `format=` and reference the [Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/)